# how to find the class name of 'deepest' div in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am aware that e.target contains the info of the element just below the cursor, but what if I want to know the class name of the div which has a table>tr>td>button in it and I'm clicking that button inside that td. I know this events bubbles up and there should be a way to find out if the div exists in that bubbling levels. Any help.

Scenario: button is inside a modal window. How do I find the modal windows class name on click of the button inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up the DOM to the nearest match:

```
var parentDiv = $(yourButton).closest('div');
```

Or in the button's `click`:

```
$(yourButton).click(function() {
  var nearestParentDiv = $(this).closest('div');
  // And read its class
  console.log(nearestParentDiv.attr('class'));
});
```

The selector `.closest()` accepts can of course be more specific than this, so if if the modal window `<div>` has some *known* class but you need to inspect its other classes, you should use the more specific selector.

Answer (score 3):

Yes as you say the event will bubble up to your div, so just make the div handle the event with `.on()` , like this:

```
$('#yourdiv').on('click',':button',function(e) {
   alert( $(e.delegateTarget).attr('class') );//alerts the classes of #yourdiv
   alert( $(this).attr('id'));//alerts the id of the clicked button (if have one)
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Fixed obtaining the reference to the original div where the event was attached. With [event.delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) from the [Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/event-object/) . Thanks Cristophe and Kevin B. for spotting the error.

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/chdh3/1/)

Comment: "for delegated events this is an element matching selector" http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This is false. `this` in that context is the clicked element, not the container you are delegating from. http://jsfiddle.net/chdh3/

Comment: Thank you both of you for spotting my error, I've updated my answer with a fix for that, using `e.delegateTarget` .

Comment: @Nelson Very nice, i didn't know about that property. That could be very useful. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parent()` to get the parent div attributes like id: http://jsbin.com/ololad/1/edit

```
$('button').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```